# Raycaster rotation problem

Tags: mathematics, rendering, rotation

I am following lodevs tutorial on Raycasting https://lodev.org/cgtutor/raycasting.html.
I was kinda successfull but for some reason while implementing a 2D Topdown view of the map and the player i have a rotation problem.
When rotating left in the raycaster view i rotate left. But in the topdown view i rotate to the right. I still am looking in the correct direction where i am supposed to be looking but this irritates me and i dont know why this is.
Here is a link to visualize what i mean: https://youtu.be/c26RObAi2Os.

```html
#include "main.h"
#include "SDL2/SDL_render.h"

int pixels[SCREEN_HEIGHT][SCREEN_WIDTH];
uint textures[8][TEX_WIDTH * TEX_HEIGHT];

int worldMap[MAP_HEIGHT][MAP_WIDTH] = {
    {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7},
    {4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7},
    {4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7},
    {4, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7},
    {4, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7},
    {4, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7},
    {4, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 5, 0, 5, 0, 5, 0, 5, 7, 0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 1},
    {4, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8},
    {4, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 1},
    {4, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8},
    {4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 7, 0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 1},
    {4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 1},
    {6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6},
    {8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4},
    {6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6},
    {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 4, 4, 4, 6, 0, 6, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3},
    {4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 6, 0, 6, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2},
    {4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 2, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2},
    {4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 6, 0, 6, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2},
    {4, 0, 6, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2},
    {4, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 6, 0, 6, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2},
    {4, 0, 6, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 6, 0, 6, 2, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2},
    {4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 6, 0, 6, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2},
    {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}};

static Player player = {.pos = {.x = 11.5, .y = 11.5},
                        .dir = {.x = -1, .y = 0},
                        .plane = {.x = 0, .y = 0.66}};

SDL_Window *window = NULL;
SDL_Renderer *renderer = NULL;
SDL_Texture *buffer = NULL;
void initSDL() {
  // Initialize SDL
  if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
    printf("SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    exit(1);
  }

  window =
      SDL_CreateWindow("Wulf", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                       SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
  if (window == NULL) {
    printf("Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    exit(1);
  }

  renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
  buffer = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888,
                             SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, SCREEN_WIDTH,
                             SCREEN_HEIGHT);
}

void destroySDL() {
  SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
  SDL_Quit();
}

void render() {
  int w = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2;
  int h = SCREEN_HEIGHT;

  for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
    // das berechnet welchem x punkt der pixel x auf der
    // kameraebene entspricht links von der richtung in der
    // die der spieler schaut ist der Wert negativ rechts
    // davon ist er positiv und in der mitte ist er NULL es
    // wird also die kameraebene auf den bildschirm gemappt
    double cameraX = 2 * (x / (double)w) - 1;
    double rayDirX = player.dir.x + player.plane.x * cameraX;
    double rayDirY = player.dir.y + player.plane.y * cameraX;

    int mapX = (int)player.pos.x;
    int mapY = (int)player.pos.y;

    double sideDistX;
    double sideDistY;

    double deltaDistX = (rayDirX == 0) ? 1e30 : fabs(1.0f / rayDirX);
    double deltaDistY = (rayDirY == 0) ? 1e30 : fabs(1.0f / rayDirY);
    double perpWallDist;

    int stepX;
    int stepY;

    int hit = 0;
    int side;

    if (rayDirX < 0) {
      stepX = -1;
      sideDistX = (player.pos.x - mapX) * deltaDistX;
    } else {
      stepX = 1;
      sideDistX = (mapX + 1.0 - player.pos.x) * deltaDistX;
    }
    if (rayDirY < 0) {
      stepY = -1;
      sideDistY = (player.pos.y - mapY) * deltaDistY;
    } else {
      stepY = 1;
      sideDistY = (mapY + 1.0 - player.pos.y) * deltaDistY;
    }

    // perform DDA
    while (hit == 0) {
      // jump to next map square, either in x-direction, or in y-direction
      if (sideDistX < sideDistY) {
        sideDistX += deltaDistX;
        mapX += stepX;
        side = 0;
      } else {
        sideDistY += deltaDistY;
        mapY += stepY;
        side = 1;
      }
      // Check if ray has hit a wall
      if (worldMap[mapY][mapX] > 0)
        hit = 1;
    }
    // Calculate distance projected on camera direction (Euclidean distance
    // would give fisheye effect!)
    perpWallDist =
        side == 0 ? (sideDistX - deltaDistX) : (sideDistY - deltaDistY);

    // Calculate height of line to draw on screen
    int lineHeight = (int)(h / perpWallDist);

    // calculate lowest and highest pixel to fill in current stripe
    int drawStart = -lineHeight / 2 + h / 2;
    if (drawStart < 0)
      drawStart = 0;
    int drawEnd = lineHeight / 2 + h / 2;
    if (drawEnd >= h)
      drawEnd = h - 1;
    // texturing calculations
    int texNum = worldMap[mapY][mapX] - 1;

    // calculate value of wallX
    // where exactly the wall was hit betwen 0 and 1 => uniform grid world
    double wallX = side == 0 ? player.pos.y + perpWallDist * rayDirY
                             : player.pos.x + perpWallDist * rayDirX;
    wallX -= floor((wallX));

    // x coordinate on the texture
    int texX = (int)(wallX * (double)TEX_WIDTH);
    if (side == 0 && rayDirX > 0)
      texX = TEX_WIDTH - texX - 1;
    if (side == 1 && rayDirY < 0)
      texX = TEX_WIDTH - texX - 1;

    // SDL_Log("y0:%i y1:%i: color:%i",drawStart,drawEnd ,color);
    double step = 1.0 * TEX_HEIGHT / lineHeight;
    // Starting texture coordinate
    double texPos = (drawStart - (float)h / 2 + (float)lineHeight / 2) * step;
    for (int y = drawStart; y < drawEnd; y++) {
      // Cast the texture coordinate to integer, and mask with (TEX_HEIGHT - 1)
      // in case of overflow
      int texY = (int)texPos & (TEX_HEIGHT - 1);
      texPos += step;
      Uint32 color = textures[texNum][TEX_HEIGHT * texY + texX];
      // make color darker for y-sides: R, G and B byte each divided through two
      // with a "shift" and an "and"
      if (side == 1)
        color = (color >> 1) & 8355711;
      pixels[y][x] = color;
    }
  }
}

void render2D() {
  int offset = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2;
  for (int y = 0; y < MAP_HEIGHT; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < MAP_WIDTH; x++) {
      if (worldMap[y][x] != 0) {
        int offsetY = y * TILE_HEIGHT;
        int offsetX = offset + x * (TILE_WIDTH);
        for (int ty = 0; ty < TILE_HEIGHT - 1; ty++) {
          for (int tx = 0; tx < (TILE_WIDTH - 1); tx++) {
            pixels[offsetY + ty][offsetX + tx] = 0x5088ff;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

void drawPlayer2D() {
  int py = player.pos.y * TILE_HEIGHT;
  int px = player.pos.x * (int)TILE_WIDTH + SCREEN_WIDTH / 2.0;
  int dx = player.dir.x * 3 + px;
  int dy = player.dir.y * 3 + py;
  SDL_Rect r = {.x = px - 5, .y = py - 5, .w = 10, .h = 10};
  SDL_Rect d = {.x = dx - 3, .y = dy - 3, .w = 6, .h = 6};

  SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
  SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &r);
  SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 125, 255, 255);
  SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &d);
}

void rotate(float rot) {
  const v2 d = player.dir, p = player.plane;
  player.dir.x = d.x * cos(rot) - d.y * sin(rot);
  player.dir.y = d.x * sin(rot) + d.y * cos(rot);
  player.plane.x = p.x * cos(rot) - p.y * sin(rot);
  player.plane.y = p.x * sin(rot) + p.y * cos(rot);
}

void generateTextures() {
  memset(textures, 0, sizeof(textures));
  for (int y = 0; y < TEX_HEIGHT; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < TEX_WIDTH; x++) {
      int xorcolor = (x * 256 / TEX_WIDTH) ^ (y * 256 / TEX_HEIGHT);
      // int xcolor = x * 256 / TEX_WIDTH;
      int ycolor = y * 256 / TEX_HEIGHT;
      int xycolor = y * 128 / TEX_HEIGHT + x * 128 / TEX_WIDTH;
      textures[0][TEX_WIDTH * y + x] =
          65536 * 254 *
          (x != y && x != TEX_WIDTH - y); // flat red texture with black cross
      textures[1][TEX_WIDTH * y + x] =
          xycolor + 256 * xycolor + 65536 * xycolor; // sloped greyscale
      textures[2][TEX_WIDTH * y + x] =
          256 * xycolor + 65536 * xycolor; // sloped yellow gradient
      textures[3][TEX_WIDTH * y + x] =
          xorcolor + 256 * xorcolor + 65536 * xorcolor; // xor greyscale
      textures[4][TEX_WIDTH * y + x] = 256 * xorcolor;  // xor green
      textures[5][TEX_WIDTH * y + x] =
          65536 * 192 * (x % 16 && y % 16);            // red bricks
      textures[6][TEX_WIDTH * y + x] = 65536 * ycolor; // red gradient
      textures[7][TEX_WIDTH * y + x] =
          128 + 256 * 128 + 65536 * 128; // flat grey texture
    }
  }
}

void playerBoundsCheck() {
  if (player.pos.x >= MAP_WIDTH) {
    player.pos.x = MAP_WIDTH - 10;
  } else if (player.pos.x < 0) {
    player.pos.x = 10;
  }
  if (player.pos.y >= MAP_HEIGHT) {
    player.pos.y = MAP_HEIGHT - 10;
  } else if (player.pos.y < 0) {
    player.pos.y = 10;
  }
}

int main() {
  initSDL();
  generateTextures();
  int pitch = SCREEN_WIDTH * sizeof(int);
  void *rawPixels = NULL;

  SDL_Event e;
  double time = 0;
  double oldTime = 0;
  bool quit = false;
  while (!quit) {
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)) {
      if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
        quit = true;
    }

    oldTime = time;
    time = SDL_GetTicks();
    double frameTime = (time - oldTime) / 1000.0;
    const float rotspeed = 5.0f * frameTime, movespeed = 5.0f * frameTime;

    const uint8_t *keystate = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
    if (keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT]) {
      rotate(-rotspeed);
    }

    if (keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT]) {
      rotate(+rotspeed);
    }

    if (keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_UP]) {
      player.pos.x += player.dir.x * movespeed;
      player.pos.y += player.dir.y * movespeed;
      playerBoundsCheck();
    }

    if (keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN]) {
      player.pos.x -= player.dir.x * movespeed;
      player.pos.y -= player.dir.y * movespeed;
      playerBoundsCheck();
    }

    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_LockTexture(buffer, NULL, &rawPixels, &pitch);

    memset(pixels, 0, sizeof(pixels));
    render();
    render2D();

    memcpy(rawPixels, pixels, pitch * SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    SDL_UnlockTexture(buffer);
    rawPixels = NULL;
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, buffer, NULL, NULL);
    drawPlayer2D();

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
  }

  return 0;
}
```